# FormulaEvaluator in Apachie POI only returns null value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to evaluate a formula in an Excel file and get the value sent back as a string.  The value in the cell appears as a date but I don't need it to be sent back as a date, I just want it as a string.

Below is my code:

```
public final class Demo {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(getCellValue());
}

    public static String getCellValue() throws Exception {
    final Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(new File("config.xlsx")));
        final Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

        final Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
        final Cell cell = row.getCell(5);

        System.err.println(cell.getCellFormula());

        final FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        final CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
        return cellValue.getStringValue();
        //Answer discovered instead of return "cellValue.getStringValue();" you must use only "return cellValue;"
    }
}
```

When I run the code the console shows me the formula that appears in the cell but for the value it only returns `null`.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

`TEXT(VLOOKUP((SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<="&G2,C:C,">="&G2)),A:C,2,0),"m/d/yyyy")
null`

**EDIT:**
Updated code

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("config.xlsx");
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("F2"); 
    Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
    Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 

    CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);

            System.out.println(cellValue.getCellType());
        //Answer discovered instead of return "System.out.println(cellValue.getCellType());" you must use only "System.out.println(cellValue);"
    wb.close();
```

Comment: Put the formula `=VLOOKUP((SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<="&G2,C:C,">="&G2)),A:C,2,0)` into a separate cell and determine what type of `CellValue` the `FormulaEvaluator` returns for this formula result. If that is a string value which only looks like a date, then the evaluation of `TEXT` will return `null`.

Comment: OK, values in `B:B` and `C:C` must be really numeric date values in Excel else it will not even work in `Excel`.  But the value in `$G2` must also be really numeric date value for working with `apache poi`'s evaluator. In Excel this can be a string value which only looks like a date.

Comment: @AxelRichter I will need to try this later when I get home but basically what I am doing is I have a range of random start and end dates.  So `G2` is a date inside one of the start/end periods, I need to figure out the starting date of the period `G2` belongs to.  The formula in `Excel` works fine.  I put the text around it because I thought it would just return the serial number like `43222` instead but I only need a string that is in the `m/d/yyyy` format so I can pass it into a `Selenium` project I am working on.

Comment: @AxelRichter Well I removed the text but still getting the same result of `VLOOKUP((SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<="&G2,C:C,">="&G2)),A:C,2,0)
null`

Comment: @AxelRichter So I updated my post up top with an updated code I am using.  When I use this code on regular numbers or simple formula like `A1+1` and I use `getNumberValue` it is returning the correct amount, but when I use it on my formula `getNumberValue` retuns `0.0` and when I run `getStringValue` I get `null`.  If I run `getCellType` it returns a `ERROR` and then if I try `getErrorValue` it returns `42` which is definitely not close to my cell value.  Any ideas? The cell is formatted as a date but the actual value of the cell would be `43362` as a number. I am completely lost here

Comment: So not possible to help without having the Excel file `config.xlsx`. Can you upload it somewhere? Maybe first creating an example `config.xlsx` containing dummy datas only but having the same issue. The byte 42 of `getErrorValue` is the `#N/A` error in Excel. But `apache poi`'s formula evaluator is not 100% like Excel. Also we need to know  what `apache poi` version you are using.

Comment: @AxelRichter Sure, here is a link to the file on my Google Drive  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XB8Jh55OX0M2GECn3a1a7tQsRO95jW2x/view?usp=sharing  It looks like it is struggling on the `VLOOKUP` and `SUMIFS` formulas but from what I read it looks like apache supports those.  I am using the latest stable version 4.0.0.  The file I uploaded is the exact file I am using, nothing special about it just some date references.  The cells I need are `F2` & `F3` & `F4` Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I cannot reproduce your issue. I've downloaded your file. Then when run following code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.File;

class ReadExcelFormulaEvaluatorExample {

 static Workbook workBook;
 static Sheet sheet;
 static FormulaEvaluator evaluator;
 static DataFormatter formatter;

 static {
  try {
   workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(new File("config.xlsx")));
   sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
   evaluator = workBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
   formatter = new DataFormatter();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 static CellValue getCellValue(int r, int c) throws Exception {
  Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
  Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
  System.err.println(cell.getCellFormula());
  CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
  return cellValue;
 }

 static String getCellContent(int r, int c) throws Exception {
  Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
  Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
  System.err.println(cell.getCellFormula());
  String cellContent = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);

  return cellContent;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("G2:");
  System.out.println(getCellValue(1, 6));

  System.out.println("Cell values:");
  for (int r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
   System.out.println(getCellValue(r, 5));
  }
  System.out.println("Cell contents:");

  for (int r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
   System.out.println(getCellContent(r, 5));
  }
  workBook.close();
 }
}
```

in environment: `Java 8`, `apache poi 4.0.0`.  It produces following output:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.0$ java -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* ReadExcelFormulaEvaluatorExample 
G2:
TODAY()-1
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [43369.0]
Cell values:
VLOOKUP(F4,A:C,2,0)
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [43362.0]
VLOOKUP(F4,A:D,4,0)
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue ["Period 10"]
SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<="&G2,C:C,">="&G2)
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [10.0]
Cell contents:
VLOOKUP(F4,A:C,2,0)
9/19/18
VLOOKUP(F4,A:D,4,0)
Period 10
SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<="&G2,C:C,">="&G2)
10
```

Btw.: Since all dates in `B:B` and `C:C` are placed in ascending order and there are not any gaps between end date in `C:C` and next start in `B:B`, the formula

`SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<="&G2,C:C,">="&G2)`

could be replaced with

`INDEX(A:A,MATCH(G2,B:B,1))`.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much.  I am still trying to go through and figure out why yours works and mine does not.  The `getCellContents` is definitely what I wanted with the `dataformatter` but the `getCellValue` look similar to my code that I took from the `apache poi` documentation.  Either way thanks again.

Comment: Ahh I see it! after evaluating the formula I was trying to do `System.out.println(cellValue.getCellType());` when all I needed was `System.out.println(cellValue);` and it works now.  But I like your code much better.  My next question would have been how to use the `dataformatter`